# Why does feather need pyarrow? (or: How to load feather data without downgrading to pandas 24?)

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow, feather

I get this error message: `Missing optional dependency 'pyarrow'.  Use pip or conda to install pyarrow.` when I run a simple command to load feather data, ie: `pd.read_feather("data.feather")`.

Surely I can install pyarrow from conda-forge, but that forces a downgrade from Pandas 25 to Pandas 24. That does not make sense to me.

I want to keep Pandas 25 *and* load feather files. How to proceed?

Comment: That is because the feather IO functionality that is used in pandas is implemented in `pyarrow`, and thus pandas needs that library to be able to read or write feather files. You should be able to install pyarrow with pandas 0.25.0 though.

Answer (score 3):

The Conda's version of pyarrow does not work properly.
Uninstall it and then install it again via pip  (the current version is 0.15.1 vs 0.13.something of Conda) - it works fine with Pandas 25.x